# I am not getting where i am wrong in changing loops

Tags: c++, for-loop, do-while

I am trying to convert this for loop into do while :

```
 for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
 {
 if(n%i==0)
   { cout<<"  "<<i;
     d++;
     s+=i;
   }
 i++
 }
```

I converted this  into this. But I am not getting the right output

```
 do
 {
   if(n%i==0)
   { cout<<"  "<<i;
     d++;
     s+=i;
   }
   i++;
 }
 while(i>n);
```

please tell me where am I wWrong.

Comment: why do you have twice "i++"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below code with my edits:  I got the output `1 2 5 10` for each loop with n arbitrarily set to 10.

```
    int i = 0;
    int n = 10;
    int d = 0;
    int s = 0;

for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
 {
 if(n%i==0)
   { 
     cout<<"  "<<i;
     d++;
     s+=i;
   }
 //i++; //commented this out. i already increments
 }

cout << endl;

    // reset variables for do while loop
    i = 1;
    n = 10;
    d = 0;
    s = 0;

do
 {
   if(n%i==0)
   { cout<<"  "<<i;
     d++;
     s+=i;
   }
   i++;
 }
 while(i<=n);  //changed condition
```

Comment: condition in do-while is incorrect.Check out the suggested edit.

Comment: the current code `while(i<=n)` will return true until i = 11.  Your suggested code `while(i<n)` will return true until i = 10.  This is the end condition of the loop and the fact that a do while loop runs at least once is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

Your loop on the second part should be while `(i <= n)`. Also, you need to initialize your variable `i` (add `i = 1` at the beginning of the looop). Also, there is a missing `;` in the line  `i++` in your first loop - also note that this is unecessary, because you are already incrementing `i` in your for loop. Adding `i++;` at the end of the for loop makes `i` increment twice in each iteraction. The corrected code looks like this:

First loop (for):

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
     if(n%i==0)
    { 
        cout<<"  "<<i;
        d++;
        s+=i;
    }
}
```

Second loop (do-while):

```
i= 1;
do
{
    if(n%i==0)
    { 
        cout<<"  "<<i;
        d++;
        s+=i;
    }
    i++;
}
while(i<=n);
```

Comment: I have corrected as you said but it still does not give me the kind of output I expected i=1;
   do
     '  {
          if(n%i==0)
          { cout<<"  "<<i;
            d++;
            s+=i;
          }
           i++;
       }
   while(i<n);'

Comment: Did you mean to increment i once or twice per interation?

Comment: I wanted it to increment once

Comment: The while condition should be (i < n + 1), because you want to enter the loop if i == n

Comment: or equivalentely, i <= n

Comment: It still does not work. I am giving you the full program `void main()
{
   clrscr();
   int n,d=0,s=0,i;
   cout<<"Enter the number : ";
   cin>>n;
   cout<<"The divisors are : ";
   i=1;
   do
   {
     if(n%i==0)
     { cout<<"  "<<i;
     d++;
     s+=i;
     }
    i++;
   }
   while(i<n+1);
   cout<<"\nThe sum of divisors is  : "<<s;
   cout<<"\nNumber of divisors is : "<<d;
   getch();
}
`

Comment: It is generating the same output here. Could you show me some test case where the code I provided doesnt work?

Comment: That code in your comment works just fine here. What error are you getting?

Comment: it should be i<n in while....because do while runs once for sure before checking the condition.

Comment: When you give an odd number as 5 or 7 as input

Comment: Im getting the correct results here. Outputs for 5 and 7:

Comment: Enter the number :  7
The divisors are :   1 7
The sum of divisors is : 8 
Number of divisors is :  2

Comment: Enter the number :  5
The divisors are :   1 5
The sum of divisors is : 6 
Number of divisors is :  2

Comment: @Gabriel Ilharco Change the condition in do while loop to i<n.

Comment: @James Kutch Change the condition in do while loop to i<n.

Comment: @Matheus Mathai, that is not correct. He wants to enter the loop when i == n, so the correct condition is i <= n.

Comment: @Matheus Mathai, feel free to tets the code with both conditions and see for ourself. Take n = 10, for example, and you will see

Comment: Great, happy to hear that =)

Answer (score 1):

Your `do while` loop needs to end with `while (i < n)` not `while (i > n)`.

Comment: understood my mistake ,Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the error is basicallly in the for loop you have declared i=1 and in do-while you havn't declare also the main mistake is you are making wrong condition check in do while it should be  `(i<n)`